# Is there a way to make time pass faster in linux

Tags: linux, time

I'm not quite sure how timekeeping works in linux short of configuring an NTP server and such.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to make time tick faster in linux.  I would like for example for 1 second to tick 10000 times faster than normal.

For clarification I don't want to make time jump like resetting a clock, I would like to increase the tick rate whatever it may be.

Answer (score 2):

This is often needed functionality for simulations and replaying incoming data or events as fast as possible.

The way people solve this issue is that they have an event loop, e.g. `libevent` or `boost::asio`. The current time is obtained from the event loop (e.g. the time when `epoll` has returned) and stored in the event loop variable *current time*. Instead of using `gettimeofday` or `clock_gettime` the time is read from that *current time* variable. All timers are driven by the event loop *current time*.

When simulating/replaying, the event loop *current time* gets assigned the timestamp of the next event, hence eliminating time durations between the events and replaying the events as fast as possible. And your timers still work and fire in between the events as they would in the real-time but without the delays. For this to work your saved event stream that your replay must contain a timestamp of each event, of course.